# Line Break Methods

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help, I tried breaking my message into different lines in my code but when I applied `<br>`, `<br>` also followed the message to my inbox. I write VB.NET, see my code below:

```vb
Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br />" _
    & "<td>Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention </td><br /><br />" _
    & "<td>Best Regards,</td> <br/ ><br/ >" _
    & "<td>Customer Care, </td><br/ >" _
    & "<td>customercare@sample.com </td><br/ >" _
    & "<strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>"
```

Below is what I keep getting as a result:

```
Dear EDWARD,<br /><br />Kindly find enclosed a copy of your debit note for your attention <br /><br />Best Regards, <br/ ><br/ >Customer Care, <br/ >customercare@sample.com <br/ ><strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>.
```

Comment: And of course you set [`IsBodyHtml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?view=netframework-4.8) to `True`?

Comment: Why do you have table data tags in there?  If you want a table then use a table. If you want free-form text with line breaks then don't use a table. Don;t combine the two.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, even when i removed table... it did not work yet.                                                       Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br />" _
    & "Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention <br /><br />" _
                  & "Best Regards, <br/ ><br/ >" _
                  & "Customer Care, <br/ >" _
                  & "customercare@sample.com <br/ >" _
                  & "<strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>"

Comment: @GSerg, the code below has worked when i set IsBodyHtml to True.     
         Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br />" _
 & "Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention <br /><br />" _
    & "Best Regards, <br/ ><br/ >" _
    & "Customer Care,<br/ >" _
    & "customercare@sample.com<br/ >" _
    & "<strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>"         Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this output going? If not a browser window, then don't use `html` tags. Use `vbCrLf` instead:

```vb
    Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & "," & vbCrLf  _
    & "Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention " & vbCrLf _
    & "Best Regards," & vbCrLf _
    & "Customer Care," & vbCrLf _
    & "customercare@sample.com" & vbCrLf _
    & "09000SAM564678FRT" & vbCrLf
```

If it _is_for a browser, then as @jmcilhinney pointed out, get rid of the table tags:

```vb
Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br />" _
    & "Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention <br /><br />" _
    & "Best Regards, <br/ ><br/ >" _
    & "Customer Care,<br/ >" _
    & "customercare@sample.com<br/ >" _
    & "<strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>"
```

Comment: the output is going to the customer as a body of an email. I have tried the vbCrLf, it didn't work.          Dim ebody As String= "Dear " & Rec.Surname & "," & vbCrLf & _               
& "Kindly find enclosed a copy Of your receipt For your attention" & vbCrLf _                   & "Best Regards " & vbCrLf _                            & "Customer Care " & vbCrLf _             
& "customercare@sample.com " & vbCrLf _                                                              
& "09000SAM564678FRT" & vbCrLf

Comment: @fujin - Did you try using just the `<br/ >` tags and removing the `<td></td>` tags as suggested?

Comment: Yes, i removed <td></td>

Comment: the code has worked when i set IsBodyHtml   to   True.
Dim ebody As String = "Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br />" _
    & "Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention <br /><br />" _
    & "Best Regards, <br/ ><br/ >" _
    & "Customer Care,<br/ >" _
    & "customercare@sample.com<br/ >" _
    & "<strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>"         Thank you for the support and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in all.

I suppose (if I well understand) you want to create lines of text as html in your mail (as html body)

Firstly `<br />`(Line Break ) never go out of `<td>` (Table Data/Cell) and `<td>` needs a `<tr>` (Table row).
So, even I think there is many `<br />`  to do that you need to put your `<br />` into a `<td>` tag.
`<td>` tag doesn’t work as a generic/normal tag like `<div>`, `<p>` etc. **As is a table cell needs to be inside a table properly**, inside a row and this row needs to be inside a table.
Outside of `<td>` tag you can put only special tags as `<th>`, `<dialog>`, `<shadow>` etc **and this tags also needs to be inside** a `<tr>` tag.

Try the code below as a correct html markup base and improve it as you want.

```
    Dim sbBody As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sbBody.AppendLine("<table>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> Dear " & Rec.Surname & ",<br /><br /> </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> Kindly find enclosed a copy of your receipt for your attention <br /><br /> </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> Best Regards,                                                  <br /><br /> </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> Customer Care,                                                 <br /><br /> </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> customercare@sample.com                                        <br /><br /> </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("<tr> <td> <strong>09000SAM564678FRT </strong>                                         </td></tr>")
    sbBody.AppendLine("</table>")
    Dim ebody As String = sbBody.ToString
```

Comment: Formatting a salutation in a table will most likely look rather ugly since there is often cell borders drawn even if you set the table attributes to not include them.

Comment: This comment you must write above (in OP question), not in this answer. However OP is free to do that OP want to do.